# QML: Event which triggers when document was completly loaded

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I work now on an application witch loads QML file and makes screenshot of a window.
That's how it looks now:

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.loadData(data);
QQuickWindow *rootObject = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(engine.rootObjects().first());

QImage image = rootObject->grabWindow();
image.save("window.png","PNG",90);
```

In this case `data` is just simple QML structure:

```js
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello, world!"
    }
    MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         //onClicked: someSingleton.makeScreenshot();
    }
    Component.onCompleted: someSingleton.makeScreenshot();
}
```

But image I get from `QQuickWindow::grabWindow()` is empty and not saved. So I tried to make it in another way through `Component.onCompleted` and it still not works. (`someSingleton.makeScreenshot()` is a function with call to `QQuickWindow::grabWindow()` like the code above). The only way to get it work is to call to this function in `MouseArea .onClicked` when a window completely loaded. So I came to conclusion that in 2 first attempts QML tree was not fully loaded.

I also tried this code:

```cpp
connect(rootObject,&QQuickWindow::afterRendering,[=] () {
    QImage image = rootObject->grabWindow();
    image.save("window.png","PNG",90);
});
```

But program's execution just hungs up on first line.

So my question - is there some event witch triggers when a QML document completely loaded?

*P.S. In real app I cannot modify QML source so all functionality have to be in C++ part. `Component.onCompleted` and `MouseArea .onClicked` here are just for test purposes*.

Comment: The code crashes for me at the `grabWindow()` call: http://pastebin.com/bK5vWpiV

Comment: @Mitch It works on my 5.4 MinGW installation on Win7. However the grabbed screen is not correctly centered much like it has been taken before the window is correctly centered. [Here is the screenshot](http://i62.tinypic.com/n6xpo4.png).

Comment: Strange... works for me on Windows 7 with Qt 5.4 as well, but not Ubuntu. Might be my Qt build.

Comment: Yes, in one of my test I've got same result - the text was not centered. As I remember it was `Component.onCompleted` on Window. It says that `Window` is still not completly loaded although `onCompleted` was called. So what an event which called after loading the document and placing all the elements at their places? And thanks guys for your comments!

Comment: I tested on Debian7 / Qt 5.4. It not crashed but the image still empty

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work if you use `Qt::DirectConnection`, as mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterRendering)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after long search, I've found the solution.As usual I just had to read the Qt documentation more carefully.

```cpp
QImage QQuickWindow::​grabWindow()
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow

***Warning:*** This function can only be called from the `GUI thread`.

```cpp
void QQuickWindow::​afterRendering()
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterRendering

***Warning:*** This signal is emitted from the `scene graph rendering thread`.

So, the slot was executed in scene graph rendering thread and hangs up due to conflicts. I've just changed the example above to be sure the slot executes in GUI thread as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

```cpp
connect(rootObject,&QQuickWindow::afterRendering,this,[=] () {
    QImage image = rootObject->grabWindow();
    image.save("window.png","PNG",90);
},Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Ah! Good old `QueuedConnection` saves the day. Good point to know about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the following doesn't work:

```
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QtGui>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void save() {
        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(sender());
        QImage image = window->grabWindow();
        image.save("window.png", "PNG", 90);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QByteArray data = "import QtQuick 2.3\n"
        "import QtQuick.Window 2.2\n"
        "Window {\n"
            "visible: true\n"
            "width: 360\n"
            "height: 360\n"
            "Text {\n"
                "anchors.centerIn: parent\n"
                "text: \"Hello, world!\"\n"
            "}\n"
            "MouseArea {\n"
                 "anchors.fill: parent\n"
            "}\n"
        "}";
    engine.loadData(data);

    QQuickWindow *rootObject = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(engine.rootObjects().first());

    Object object;
    QObject::connect(rootObject, SIGNAL(afterRendering()), &object, SLOT(save()));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

It could be that the usage is incorrect, or there's actually a bug somewhere. I'm not sure. It's worth asking on the mailing list, or creating a bug report if you're unsure.

However, if you use [frameSwapped()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#frameSwapped) instead, it works:

```
    QObject::connect(rootObject, SIGNAL(frameSwapped()), &object, SLOT(save()));
```

Comment: Hmm ... so strange ... frameSwapped works but afterRendering not.

Comment: Worth a mail to the mailing list to shed some light on this behaviour.